# Show metabox for a special role

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I have special roles on my site.
I use easy digital download.
My user has access to the download page. I want the metabox not to see the number of sales.
Can I hide this metabox for this role or user?

Of course, now that I had to, I deleted it with CSS  (`display : none`)
Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The **Download stats** Metabox has a check for `view_product_stats` capability in EDD codes.
in `/easy-digital-downloads/includes/admin/downloads/metabox.php` Line:`42`

```
if ( current_user_can( 'view_product_stats', get_the_ID() ) ) {
    /** Product Stats */
    add_meta_box(
        'edd_product_stats',
        sprintf( __( '%1$s Stats', 'easy-digital-downloads' ),
        edd_get_label_singular(), edd_get_label_plural() ),
        'edd_render_stats_meta_box',
        $post_type,
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
```

You can simply remove the `view_product_stats` capability for Your special user role.

```
global $wp_roles;
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'your_special_role', 'view_product_stats' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Hector's answer is most appropriate in this situation given that he has created a *special user role* that you can target with his code.

For others that don't have custom user roles but would like to hide certain metaboxes, you can do something like what I do to ensure that no one below an Editor level can access some specific metaboxes:

```
// Removes certain Metaboxes
function remove_post_metaboxes() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) { // Enter your desired Capability to target specific Roles
    remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','post','side' ); // Format Metabox
    remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv','post','side' ); // Category Metabox
    remove_meta_box( 'adv-tagsdiv','post','side' ); // Tags (Simple Tags) Metabox
    remove_meta_box( 'st-clicks-tags','post','advanced' ); // Tags (Simple Tags) Metabox
    remove_meta_box( 'edit-flow-notifications','post','advanced' ); // EditFlow UserGroups Notifications Metabox
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_post_metaboxes');
```

SO you decide which Capability to target (since WP prefers that you use current_user_can instead of targeting specific Roles), then you just need to know the *name* of the metabox (use something like Inspect Element while in a Post where you see the metabox you want removed/hidden to find its name - the example above is the ones I remove for all non-Editors) and then if you want it removed from Posts or Pages, as well as where it normally resides.   Add this to your Child Theme's functions.php file.

More information here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/